# App not appearing in the Market for some devices

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, google-play, compatibility

I already search a lot of similar topics on SO, but I can't figure out what is going wrong. My app does not appear for some devices (Galaxy S5 Android 5.0 and Nexus 5 Android 6.0 are examples), but it just require an Internet permission. Bellow is my manifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="true"/>

<permission android:name="com.mycompany.acbeu.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"  android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.mycompany.acbeu.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"  android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" android:required="false"/>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

I read some things about "copy protection", but the devices presenting the problem does not have a modified Android version. I cant find how turn off copy protection too. The application name is "Acbeu".

**Is there some way to know why the device is not compatible with my app?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing

```
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
...
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
...
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
...

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
```

tags for your `<compatible-screens>` configs. By omitting those tags, you are explicitly not allowing devices with high resolution screens to use your app. If you intend for your app to be used on all Android devices, just get rid of the `<compatible-screens>` section. It is for restricting access to your app by devices that do not fit the explicit screen size/resolution criteria specified within that tag, so in your case you probably don't need it since you're listing all the screen sizes anyway.

Take a look [here for the official explanation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html).

Comment: It's true that there's no point in including compatible-screens in manifest if you are going to support everything.

Comment: Ironically I added this section to force compatibility in an attempt to solve the problem. Adding the "xxhdpi" and "xxxhdpi" tags causes compilation error, so I removed the <compatible-screens> section and the compatibible devices count has increased. Thank you!

Comment: @ArivanBastos I'm not trying to steal some credit there, but it is not necessary to add **supports-screens** and **compatible-screens** tags on your manifest.